# Unity calling method on another script using Invoke

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have two scripts, one of them restarts the scene and the other is a countdown timer than calls the restart scene method in the first script. However, it's not restarting and I don't understand why even though there are no errors.

The first script that restarts the scene:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.SceneManagement;

public class LevelComplete : MonoBehaviour
{
    public void LoadNextLevel()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex + 1);
    }

    public void Exit()
    {
        Application.Quit();
        Debug.Log("Exit");
    }

    public void Restart()
    {
        SceneManager.LoadScene(sceneBuildIndex: 1);
        Debug.Log("restart pressed");
    }
}
```

The second script that's supposed to restart the scene after a countdown timer ends:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class TimerCounDown : MonoBehaviour {

    [SerializeField] private Text uiText;

    [SerializeField] private float MainTimer;

    private float timer;
    private string canCount;
    private bool doneOnece;
    public float restartDelay = 5f;
    private string methName;

    private void Update()
    {
        timer -= Time.deltaTime; 
        Debug.Log((MainTimer - (-timer)));

        if ((MainTimer - (-timer)) >0)
        {
            canCount = (MainTimer - (-timer)).ToString("F1") + " Seconds until end";
            uiText.text = canCount;
        }
        else
        {
            uiText.text = "level complete lefel will be restarted in 5 seconds";
            // GetComponent<LevelComplete>();
            // Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
            // GetComponent<LevelComplete>().Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

I am trying to restart it with `Invoke` but it can't take `GetComponent<LevelComplete>().Restart()` as parameter so I decided to just simply fire this method and it doesn't work. I don't understand why and how to fix it. Please help me if you know where the problem is and the solution to it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Invoke` is a method belonging to a `MonoBehaviour` instance.

When you call `Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);` directly, the runtime will try and find a method called "Restart" within the `TimerCountDown` class since its where you called `Invoke` from, which doesn't exist. This explains why nothing happens.

The correct way would be to first reference the `LevelComplete` instance and then using that to call `Invoke`:

```
LevelComplete levelComplete = GetComponent<LevelComplete>();
levelComplete.Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);
```

Which will correctly look for the "Restart" method within the `LevelComplete` class.

Comment: actualy its throwing this error `NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
TimerCounDown.Update () (at Assets/Scripts/TimerCounDown.cs:32)`

Comment: line 32 right now is  `levelComplete.Invoke("Restart", restartDelay);`

Comment: That would mean `GetComponent<LevelComplete>()` returned null. Are your LevelComplete and TimerCountDown scripts attached to the same object?

Comment: script connected to the UI text object in  script parameter UIText  taking same object  so it  can show timer and message

Comment: thanks I attached it to timer object and it start working :) Thank you !!